# Incorrect Phone labels for Google+ contacts

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, google-plus

On the Samsung Galaxy S3 contacts synced from Google+ will have their phone number labels garbled.

In the following image you can see the three phone numbers associated with my contact. They are labeled (in swedish, english translation in parentheses):

1. **Arbete** (Work)
2. **Personsökare** (Pager)
3. **Annat** (Other).

[image]

In Google+ they are however labeled correctly, (swedish translation in parentheses):

1. **Home** (Hem)
2. **Mobile** (Mobil)
3. **Work** (Arbete)

I've tried all I can think of to get the labels correct but no luck:

- Syncing with Google+
- Delete and re-add the contact.
- Changing the phone number labels in Google+ and re-syncing.
- Deleting cache and data from Google+ app.
- Deleting cache and data from Google Contacts Sync.

Doing some Google searches yielded only [one relevant link](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-discuss/OUWMGGBLB1A). Same problem, no solution.

Does anyone know if this is a confirmed bug or is there a fix?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use a [different contact app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=contacts&c=apps&hl=en)? Try [exporting your Google contacts as Outlook CSV](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/24911?hl=en) then open the CSV file in Excel (or similar). Do the labels in the file line up with the shuffled labels on your phone? I'm betting this is the Samsung contacts app incorrectly parsing the information from Google.

Comment: @Mr.Buster That's my guess too hence the question if this is a confirmed bug and if there is a fix for it. In the exported CSV file all labels are correct.

Comment: As to whether it's a confirmed bug or the possibility of an official fix from Samsung: your Google search is as good as mine (I didn't find anything when I briefly looked). As far as a workaround is concerned, though, I'd try a different contact app to see if you get the same result. Knowing the labels are correct upon export makes me more confident that it's the app rather than Google Contacts.

Comment: I found it even more weird that you could export your Google Contacts and check the labels were correct. If I interpreted correctly, you're facing the same problem as me, all of my friends from Google+ have "pagers" on their contacts on my phone (a Samsung Nexus S - no proprietary software, although it's also a Samsung). But Google+ contacts are only present when I sync them on the phone. In my case, they're not part of Google Contacts, although I can see their connections (but cannot find their numbers there). Still a bug with the latest version of Google+ (where I guess the problem resides).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is a conflict between the Samsung's Phone app and G+'s way of storing labels. Using stock Android Phone app might solve your problem.